# Embedded Board Replies to Pings in Wireshark but not in Windows

Tags: windows, ping, icmp, embedded

I have an embedded board (running a Cortex-M7), and LWIP for the networking library. MAC is integrated to the CPU, but has an external PHY.

I go ahead and initialize LWIP, and when I ping the board from my laptop, I see the replies 100% of the time in wireshark. However, Windows does not see all of the replies.

The physical connection between the board and the laptop is directly wired (both ends support auto MDI-X), and then I have also tried connecting the board to our office network, which my laptop is connected to wirelessly. There's no real change in behavior except for a few more ms of latency.

I figure this is just Windows being stupid, but the same problem occurred with my coworker's macbook. I figure if it was a windows firewall problem, we wouldn't see any responses in windows or wireshark. I've tried manually adding the board to the windows ARP cache (arp -s) and saw no change.

Generally, windows sees ~2/3 of the responses. However, if I change how the checksums on the board are generated (the ICMP checksum), it can drop down to about 40%. Wireshark says all the checksums are correct in both cases, however.

What could possibly be causing wireshark to see the ping responses be valid, but not windows?

Screenshot attached: powershell with the ping command and then wireshark with the relevant packets. The board is .42, my laptop is .98. The first ping gets replied to in roughly 50ms, the other ones are 3-4ms (on the office network with a wireless link to the laptop)

[wireshark and powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcwTl.png)